# Some hotkeys not working for certain apps

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I'm trying to understand why select hotkeys will not work in certain apps. For example, <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> will not work in WhatsApp to make text bigger, and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> will not work in Joplin to make it full screen.

My suspicion is that another application is hijacking this hotkey, but how do I verify this? How do I check which commands the computer is actually executing?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is being hijacked.  To make an app full screen or to make text larger, it must be supported by the application.  This holds true for not only shortcuts, but text substitution as well.

A quick search of the [Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201236) for the Full Screen shortcut says this:

> Control-Command-F: Use the app in full screen, if supported by the app.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, considering that WhatsApp has `ctrl + +` bound to make text bigger (as seen in View), yet it does nothing. `ctrl + -` properly makes text smaller

Comment: Many apps, for convenience, accept Cmd - or Cmd = rather than insisting on Cmd +, which is for most people actually Cmd/shift =

Comment: fair enough, that's an oversight on my part brought on by as you mentioned, convenience >.<

Comment: Maybe I wasn't totally clear in the OP however, since I am in fact able to make all of my apps fullscreen. The problem is being able to make it fullscreen with hotkeys, not just by pressing the green button in the top left corner of the window

Comment: The app, not only has to support full screen, it has to support the shortcut as well